# How did Ravan get 10 heads? What are the names of those heads?

Tags: ramayana, ravana

As Ravan had 10 heads, Does each head have individual names? Did Ravana got all names for his heads?

How he had got 10 heads?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ravana was born with ten heads.

His birth is mentioned in the [Chapter 9 of Uttara Kanda](http://ancientvoice.wikidot.com/src-vrm:ram7-9) 
 Uttara Kanda of Ramayana as well as [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2324/5212) answer by user [Keshav Srinivasan](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/36/keshav-srinivasan). It is written that he was born with ten heads. From

> Having been thus accosted, the girl, O Rama, after a length of time brought forth a very terrible and hideous offspring having the form of a Raksha, **having ten necks**, furnished with large teeth, and resembling a heap of collyrium, with coppery lips, twenty arms, huge faces, and flaming hair. On his having been born, jackals with flaming mouths and other ferocious beasts began to gyrate on the left. And that god showered down blood ;and the clouds uttered forth harsh sounds.

The names of the ten heads are not mentioned in the Uttara Kanda or Ramayana. I presume that there are no names to them.

Due to these ten heads, he got the names 'Dashagriva', 'Dashakantha', 'Dahsaanana'. As he was a descandant of Pulastya Brahma, he was also called as 'Paulastya'.

The name Ravana is given by Lord Shiva when he tried to uplift the mount Kailasa. It is from [chapter 16](http://ancientvoice.wikidot.com/src-vrm:ram7-16) of Uttara Kanda which is also explained in [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/20188/5212) answer by user [Arya](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/7075/arya).

> **And as in consequence of thy arms having been hurt by the mountain, thou hast uttered a terrific yell, which struck horror unto the three worlds and put them shaking, therefore, O King, thy name shall be Ravana. And Devas and men and Yakshas and others living on earth shall call thee Ravana terror to creatures**. So, O Paulastya, which way thou wishest, and permitted by me, O Lord of Rakshasas, go thou.

Answer (score 5):

I heard another story

The 3 bros (Ravana, Kum and Vib) do yagna to Brahma. But Ravana is not comfortable with yagna and feels out of place. He cannot focus. So, to impress Brahma and speeden the process, he cuts his own head and puts it into fire. Brahma, much too impressed, puts it back. Ravana repeats. Brahma repeats. And so they play on for about 10 times in toto. Finally Brahma, thinks ‘Enough is enough!’ and appears before them. Hence, Ravana is said to possess 10 heads!

Ravana’s 10 heads denote 6 shashtras & 4 vedas that he mastered in his lifetime.

His ten heads also represent 10 human emotions:

1. Kaam – Lust
2. Krodha – Anger
3. Moha – Delusion
4. Lobha – Greed
5. Mada – Pride
6. Maatsarya – Envy
7. Manas – Mind
8. Buddhi – Intellect
9. Chita – Will
10. Ahamkara - Ego

Comment: This is also from Uttara Kanda. But the heads were already there during his penance. He cut his nine heads but Brahma restored back. And these are ten different heads not a single one. Do you have sources for the representation of ten heads?

Comment: see but modern author https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/15150/what-do-the-10-heads-of-ravana-signify

Answer (score 0):

Ravan is is depicted with 10 head in bakthi marg scriptures. Bakthi marg scriptures are writen by rishi muni and not devi devtha or supreme soul shiva. In reality ravan raj means 10 openion of 5 narayana and 5 laskmi ( they are not worshiped in hindu scriptures. Only sathya narayana is worshiped. Ravan is the symbol of kama krodha ect because those 10 people did not listen to one openion of supreme soul shiva and they made their own openion. the five wifes are also the one who has influenced the five elements. This is why maya is called powerful she makes your intelect turn away from supreme soul and as a result dwapara and kaliyuga is created. these are yuga of kalaha and pain . It is when supreme soul enter shanker and he makes shanker equal to supreme soul then the old world will get destroyed and maya surrender and ravana is killed( god does not kill any one these five narayana seed souls of five religion( islam budha christian athiesm and arya samaj( congress party0. Sanyasi ( bjp) and sikhs are not included in the head of ravana. Sanyasi do not respect gods and supreme soul they say aham brahmasya which means i am supreme soul. but sanyasi and sikhs are rajya snehi. Sikh fought against islamic invasion when sun dynasty kings like pritwi raj and all lost spiritual power. But sanyasi and budhist ran away to himalaya. source of information wwww.pbks.info

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Hindusim SE. Please take a [TOUR](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/tour) of this site to get acquainted. Answers here must be backed-up with "authoritative sources/references". Kindly visit [Guidelines for new users answering questions](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125/guidelines-for-new-users-answering-questions). For more info please do visit: [the HSE Help Center](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help). Have an enriching journey!!